# Trouble running SSIS package programmatically and from command line (DTEXEC)

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I am attempting to execute an SSIS package programmatically using C#.

```
Application app = new Application();
Package package = app.LoadPackage(pkgFullPath, null);
package.Execute();
```

I am getting an error saying:

```
Error in Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.TaskHost/SSIS.Pipeline : To run a SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install Conditional Split of Integration Services or higher.

Error in Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.TaskHost/SSIS.Pipeline : To run a SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install Lookup of Integration Services or higher.
```

I am using SSIS in Visual Studio 2010, but executing the C# code from an nunit test in VS 2012 (running .Net 4.0)

The package runs fine inside the SSIS project in VS 2010 if I launch it with debugging (press F5), but it fails with the same error if I try to run it using dtexec from the command line (same failure in both 32 and 64 bit version of dtexec). It also fails with the same error if I launch it from inside Visual Studio using ctrl + F5 (without debugging)

I have found articles online that suggest it's related to a 64 bit v 32 bit problem, but I am seeing the same error when running both versions of dtexec. I am using version 11.0.2100.60 of dtexec, which matches the version of the SQL Server Integration Services Designer in VS 2010.

I don't get the error if I run a simple package without a conditional split and lookup. Do I have to install something extra in order to run this outside of Visual Studio?

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the integration service is installed properly ? BIDS and SSDT will be able to execute the package. If you want to use dtexec or run it programmatically, Integration services must be installed.

Check the services running on your system. As in your scenario, "SQL Server Integration service" either won't be there or in STOPPED mode.

Comment: In the package properties, have you tried adjusting the Run64BitRuntime property? [reference](http://goo.gl/QjhgFp)

Comment: Thanks guys. I hope some of these ideas might be helpful for other people with similar problems. However, my project ended up going in a different direction, so I no longer have the environment set up to attempt new solutions.

Answer (score 4):

In continuation to my above comment,if the service is installed properly, then it might be an issue regarding the rights(I see that you are using SQL 2012) of the account the packages is executed from.

Refer http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213130.aspx

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

This is VB Code, but can be easily translated to C#.
Try running a SQL command that executes the SSIS Package.

Something like:

```vb
Try
    'Job implementation goes here
    Dim jobConnection As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    Dim jobCommand As SqlCommand
    Dim jobParameter As SqlParameter
    Dim jobReturnValue As SqlParameter
    Dim jobResult As Integer


    jobConnection = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(SSISConnectionString)
    jobCommand = New SqlCommand("msdb.dbo.sp_start_job", jobConnection)
    jobCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

    jobReturnValue = New SqlParameter("@RETURN_VALUE", SqlDbType.Int)
    jobReturnValue.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue
    jobCommand.Parameters.Add(jobReturnValue)


    jobParameter = New SqlParameter("@job_name", SqlDbType.VarChar)
    jobParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
    jobCommand.Parameters.Add(jobParameter)
    jobParameter.Value = packageName

    jobConnection.Open()
    jobCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    jobResult = DirectCast(jobCommand.Parameters("@RETURN_VALUE").Value, Integer)

    jobConnection.Close()


    Select Case jobResult
        Case 0
            'Successful run
        Case Else
            Throw New Exception("SQLAgent Job failed to start!")
    End Select


Catch ex As Exception
    Return ex
End Try
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the microsoft [Install Integration Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143731.aspx) web page:

"Some SQL Server components that you can select for installation on the Feature Selection page of the Setup Wizard install a partial subset of Integration Services components. These components are useful for specific tasks, but the functionality of Integration Services will be limited. For example, the Database Engine Services option installs the Integration Services components required for the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard. The SQL Server Data Tools option installs the Integration Services components required to design a package, but the Integration Services service is not installed and you cannot run packages outside of SQL Server Data Tools. To ensure a complete installation of Integration Services, you must select Integration Services on the Feature Selection page."

That's why you can run SSIS packages from within Microsoft tools, but not from outside those tool. Strangely it only falls over on certain types of components.

If you follow their advice on that page for a full install of integration services components, this should solve the problem.

"For a complete installation of Integration Services, together with the tools and documentation for developing and managing packages, select both Integration Services and the following Shared Features:

- SQL Server Data Tools to install the tools for designing packages.
- Management Tools-  Complete to install SQL Server Management Studio
  for managing packages.

  - Client Tools SDK to install managed assemblies
    for Integration Services programming.

"